# BIOS only seeing 4 of 6 cores

Tags: bios, computer-building, multi-core

So, I'm trying to put together a PC. I have an AMD 1090T (6 cores), and a gigabyte UD5 motherboard (the 890FX one).
When I go to "Advanced BIOS Features", it only shows cores 2, 3, 4, 5. Where are the other 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you updated the BIOS to the latest version? That chip was released after the motherboard, so you will likely need to update to be able to properly use the newer CPU.

Comment: No, I haven't updated anything. I downloaded the lastest bios just now. There are 3 update files, however. Do I need to install each one separately, or will the latest one just do everything?

Comment: @CromTheDestroyer - The latest is usually fine. If you are unsure, you can read the release notes for it and it will tell you if you need a certain intermediate version, but this usually isn't the case.

Comment: I'm trying to install it from a USB. I got the .exe on the FAT32 usb stick, ran the autoextraction, plugged it into the motherboard, but the Q-Flash program doesn't see the USB. It just sees "Floppy A" and "Floppy B", which is strange because I have no floppy drives.

Comment: Heh, I got it.  
It does see the USB after all, but the USB is "Floppy B". This is so stupid.